# How from number_format function I can remove the cents part in PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting

From this code:

```
$total = 750;
number_format($total, 2, ',', ' ').'<sup>$</sup>';
```

I get `750,00$`.

How can I remove the `,00` part ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just change the `2` to `0` in the call to `number_format`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: A comma for a decimal point, looks weird to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `,00` from the result.You must change your code to

```
$total = 750;
number_format($total, 0, ',', ' ').'<sup>$</sup>';
```